# the location of the file for DSpace

Tags: file, location, dspace

Tell me which file contains the non-exclusive license from the dspace developers (note: place your own license here
This sample license is provided for informational purposes only.

NON-EXCLUSIVE DISTRIBUTION LICENSE...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying "please" would have been nice.

This is the file https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace/config/default.license

Answer (score 0):

We're happy to help, but for something like this you could save yourself some waiting.  'grep' is your friend:

```
mhwood@toolshed ~/dspaces/DS-3879 $ grep "This sample license" . -r
./config/default.license:This sample license is provided for informational purposes only.
mhwood@toolshed ~/dspaces/DS-3879 $
```